# Query Entity with secondary and condition

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

With sqlalchemy (on a postgres-DB) I would like to query some ORM-entities based on information in a secondary table. I cannot figure out how to obtain the desired result.

Consider with declarative Base this (oversimplified) example

```
class A(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'a'
  Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
  Column('properties', JSON)

class B(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'b'
  Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
  Column('properties', JSON)

class AtoB(Base):  #a m2m secondary
  __tablename__ = 'atob'
  Column('a_id', ForeignKey(A.id))
  Column('b_id', ForeignKey(B.id))
  Column('valid', Boolean())
```

now, after have filled in some objects and their associations, I'd like to query the Union of all  Objects `A`, which:

- have no entry in the AtoB table, or
- have an entry in the AtoB table, but where this entry is not valid (`AtoB.valid==False`)

I'd like to obtain a single list of unique entities of 'A', which fulfill the above criteria

My approaches, mainly trying constructs with constructs `union()` or `.filter(A.id.in_(...))` to achieve this have not been met with success. Maybe somebody here could help. Thanks

Comment: In other words you're looking for A for which no AtoB **exists** that has `valid` true?

Comment: 'In other words you're looking for A for which no AtoB exists that has valid true?' True; I guess I could dig deeper in the `exists()`-clauses; lets see if I can apply this to my 'not-quite-so-simple' real problem

Comment: Update: tried ```sess.query(A).join(AtoB).filter(~exists().where(AtoB.valid == False )).all()``` with empty result list [expected one freshly created `A()`]. So that didn't work

Comment: Close, you don't need a join in this case, but do need to correlate the exists subquery with the enclosing query, i.e. `~exists().where(and_(AtoB.valid, AtoB.a_id == A.id))`.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing me in the right direction here; I might have a small sly in the formulation of my question, which adds a bit more complexity. The second point of my condition should be formulated better: have *Any* entry in the AtoB table, but where this entry is not valid (AtoB.valid==False). I have this now solved with a `union()` pattern on two `filter(exist())`-patterns. I will formulate an answer to my question. Thanks for the help

Comment: OKay, thought I had solved this problem, but I now encounter an other error, that is more connected with the JSON column in postgres; my posted answer succeeded against a in memory-db on sqlite, but failed with postgres with the following error: `(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) could not identify an equality operator for type json`. My guess is that the JSON type, which is special in postgres, while sqlite is just using a parsed string, is somewhat used to identify uniqueness of entries. Any ideas

Comment: I just found out, that `union_all` foregoes a check for the uniqueness of returned elements, so i it overcomes the error I previously encountered, however i fear that this will return me the direct sum of all items in both sets, not the set of unique tiems in both sets. Per constructions it does not matter for me in this case, as they are one and the same...

Answer (score 0):

With the pointers of @Ilja Everilä I was able to find a solution to my problem.

However, there is a slight ambiguity in the formulation of the second selection criterion (bullet-point). Formulating this point more precise: "having *any* entry in AtoB table, with this entry's property being `valid==False`"

Then we can construct an `union` from all elements which fulfill criertion one and this which fulfill criterion two:

```
session.query(A).filter(~exists().where(AtoB.a_id == A.id)).union(
   session.query(A).filter(exists().where(and_(AtoB.valid == False, AtoB.a_id == A.id)))
)
```

Comment: some restrictions apply here; see comments in the original question